# How to run the Online VSCode editor provided by coder.com

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I was looking for an online editor to run asp.net core application and found that coder.com provides VS Code as an online editor for developing scalable applications, but i am not sure how to access the code editor provided by coder.com. could someone let know about this.

I tried to run the docker link provided by coder.com below, but nothing seems to work out.

docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8443:8443 -v "${PWD}:/home/coder/project" codercom/code-server --allow-http --no-auth

https://github.com/cdr/code-server

Comment: How does it not work? You are binding it to `localhost`, are you trying to access it on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

You first need an online code editor and use it for your purpose,
you can use `Monaco Editor`.

I think coder used it too.

https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor

Comment: Thanks amir, but how could i possibly run asp.net core application there